# Direct all path and file calls to /index.php if not found with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm attempting to make all path and file requests direct to /index.php if they do not exist.

Currently the root (root /var/www/mysite.local/html/public/) only has one file (index.php) and no sub-directories.

The goal is that unless a path and/or file name exist, no matter what the path(s) or filename are, regardless of extension (.php .jpg .gif .html .whatever), the request should direct to /index.php

Currently this only works for paths (/ or /something/or/other/).

This is what I have for my /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.local

```
server {
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/mysite.local/html/public/;
            index index.php;
            server_name mysite.local;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_local.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_local.error.log;

            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
                         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                         deny all;
            }

            location = /favicon.ico {
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                         allow all;
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
           }

            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                         expires max;
                         log_not_found off;
           }
}
```

Can someone tell me what changes I need to make to accomplish my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why its only working for paths is, that it's only working for that location block. Your `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` should be doing exactly what you want. The "proplem" is, that nginx will check this location block last, due to the importance order defined by nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#how-nginx-chooses-which-location-to-use-to-handle-requests

So if you access any .js file, you will jump into the last location block and there is nowhere defined it should use the index.php as fallback. I think adding the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to every location block should solve your problem. Tho it might not work inside the php location block.